# High-level programming with hardware communication

Tags: c#, c, dll, driver, hardware

In a C# application which controls actual hardware movement, how does the communication take place?

If a PC is connected to other hardware via USB and the low level programming has already been done for the device (assume with C), how *would* high-level C# send and receive commands from the device? Would it just be a case of connecting to the DLL of the C code and doing it that way?

I'm looking for a generalised discussion on such high-level programming to driver scenarios. This is more of a hypothetical scenario however, so there aren't any details I can give to clue you in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, often there is a .DLL with `C` exports that you call.

Sometimes you might find it hard to call some of the exports directly from C# using P/Invoke. In such cases, you can usually write a simple `C` DLL which wraps the calls and provides an alternative interface more compatible with P/Invoke.

I have also had to interface with devices which appear to be files. In those cases you have to open a file via the Windows API [`CreateFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, using a special filename syntax:

`"\\.\deviceName"`

I've also had to use P/Invoke to use some of the Windows API USB functions such as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

So as you can see, there are several ways to access hardware libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Communicating with the hardware is usually involves a layered stack.

```
application
---------------------------------------------------
glue code (assembly) (managed code)
---------------------------------------------------
user space library (static or DLL) (unmanaged code)
---------------------------------------------------
user space driver interface
---------------------------------------------------
kernel space driver
---------------------------------------------------
hardware
```

Some of these layers may be optional.